# How can I initialize new Sentry instance after init?

Tags: javascript, sentry, raven

my project contains `Raven` SDK (`raven-js`) at the moment in order to report errors to Sentry.

When I want to initialize a new instance for reporting another Sentry project (another frame), I use:

```
const newInstance = new raven.Client()
...
newInstance.config(dsn).install()
```

What is the way to get a new instance with `@sentry/browser` library?

Tried to:

```
new Sentry.BrowserClient()
```

But it says it needs `dsn` to pass.

Is there any way to get a new instance without setting its `dsn` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires config object, not `dsn` itself.

```js
const client = new Sentry.BrowserClient({});
```

Comment: This call throws an exception, for not passing `dsn`

Comment: Can you provide a repro? (or preferably write a GH issue as well)
I just tested it and it works fine for me.